# How do I create a point-symbol-mark with a png-icon?

Tags: geotools

I use StyleFactory and would like to have my point geometries drawn with a png-icon instead of a "wellKnownName"-circle/cross/etc...

```
Mark mark = sf.createMark(ff.literal(wellKnownName), stroke, fill, ff.literal(size), ff.literal(0));
```

How do I do that with the StyleFactory, is it possible?

Comment: Graphic takes a list of marks, a list of graphic icons, and a list of something else I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your `Graphic` the first argument is a list of `GraphicalSymbol`s. So you can provide a series of symbols that the renderer works through until it comes to one it can draw. These can be `Mark`s (wellknown or otherwise) or `ExternalGraphic`s.

```
StyleFactory sf = CommonFactoryFinder.getStyleFactory();
FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();

int size = 10;
String wellKnownName = "circle";
Stroke stroke = sf.createStroke(ff.literal("#ff0000"), ff.literal(2));
Fill fill = sf.createFill(ff.literal("#000000"));
List<GraphicalSymbol> symbols = new ArrayList<>();
ExternalGraphic graphic = sf.createExternalGraphic(
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver-2.21.0/rest/resource/styles/burg02.svg", "image/svg+xml");
symbols.add(graphic);
Mark mark = sf.createMark(ff.literal(wellKnownName), stroke, fill, ff.literal(size), ff.literal(0));
symbols.add(mark);
Graphic symbol = sf.graphic(symbols, ff.literal(1.0), ff.literal(size), null, null, null);
```

Comment: ExternalGraphic graphic = sf.createExternalGraphic("file:///" + filePath, "image/png"      );

Comment: Is there a way to set a color for the (svn) Graphic symbol in Ians answer above, without editing the svn file?

Comment: see https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/pointsymbols.html#svg-parameters

Comment: Thanks,
   ExternalGgraphic = sf.createExternalGraphic(
  "file:///" + filePath +
  "?fill=#" + fillRed + fillGreen + fillBlue + 
  "&fill-opacity=" + opacity + 
  "&outline=#" + outlineRed + outLineGreen + outlineBlue + 
   "&outline-opacity=" + outLineOpacity +
   "&outline-width=" + lineWidth
   , "image/svg+xml");